# Can we charge any two bodies (insulators) by rubbing?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, insulators

I am not talking about the usual glass rubbed with silk rather **any** two insulators found in nature.
If we rub them, will they get charged? Like cotton and plastic etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any pair of two *different* materials, it's basically guaranteed that the triboelectric effect will charge one of them positively and one of them negatively. However, for a pair of materials that are too close to each other at the triboelectric scale, the charges may be zero. See a page for more:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

But if the materials are genuinely different, it is virtually impossible that the charge of both would be "exactly" zero.